# How can I include or exclude a record according to a boolean parameter using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am not so into **Spring Data JPA** and I have the following doubt about how to implement a simple query.

I have this **AccomodationMedia** entity class mapping the **accomodation_media** on my database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accomodation_media")
public class AccomodationMedia {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "id_accomodation")
    private Long idAccomodation;

    @Column(name = "is_master")
    private boolean isMaster;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "media")
    private byte[] media;

    private String description;

    private Date time_stamp;

    public AccomodationMedia() {
    }

    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    // GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
}
```

The instance of this class represents the photo associated to an accomodation (an hotel)

So as you can see in the prvious code snippet I have this field :

```
@Column(name = "id_accomodation")
private Long idAccomodation;
```

that contains the id of an accomodation (the id of an hotel on my database).

I also have this boolean field that specify if an image is the **master image** or not:

```
@Column(name = "is_master")
private boolean isMaster;
```

So, at this time, in my repository class I have this method that should return **all the images associated to a specific hotel**:

```
@Repository
public interface AccomodationMediaDAO extends JpaRepository<AccomodationMedia, Long> {

   List<AccomodationMedia> findByIdAccomodation(Long accomodationId);

}
```

I want to modify this method passing also the boolean parameter that specify if have to be returned also the master image or only the images that are not master.

So I tryied doing in this way:

```
List<AccomodationMedia> findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster(Long accomodationId, boolean isMaster);
```

but this is not correct because setting to **true** the **isMaster** parameter it will return only the **master image** (because it is first selecting all the Accomodation having a specific accomodation ID and then the one that have the **isMaster** field setted as **true**).

So, how can I correctly create this query that use the **isMaster** boolean parameter to include or exclude the **AccomodationMedia** instance that represent my master image?

I know that I can use also native SQL or HQL to do it but I prefer do it using the "query creation from method names"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have how to test this, but essentially your final query should be:

```
id_accomodation = ?1 AND (is_master = ?2 OR is_master = false)
```

So I would try the following method signature:

```
findByIdAccomodationAndIsMasterOrIsMasterFalse(Long accomodationId, boolean isMaster);
```

Comment: Great one! I'd still vote to rather not use query derivation here as the method becomes awkward to read. Rather stick to the JPAQL query and give the method a more meaningful name.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with two methods one for isMaster true, while second for false value like this:

`List<AccomodationMedia> findByIdAccomodationAndIsMasterFalse(Long accomodationId);`

`List<AccomodationMedia> findByIdAccomodationAndIsMasterTrue(Long accomodationId);`

Answer (score 0):

Change your acommodation id as accomodationId instead of idAccomodation. When you write `findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster` spring confusing **findById**AccomodationAndIsMaster

Try this this convention

```
@Column(name = "accomodation_id")
private Long accomodationId;
```